# O que são descritores de arquivos e diretórios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diretório, sistema-operacional, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou estudando o `módulo os` da biblioteca padrão do `Python` e percebo que em muitos casos uma função é permitida receber como parâmetro um `descritor de arquivo ou diretório` alguns exemplos são:

> `os.fchdir(fd)`
>   Change the current working directory to the directory
>   represented by the `file descriptor fd`. The descriptor must `refer to an
>   opened directory`, not an open file. As of Python 3.3, this is
>   equivalent to `os.chdir(fd).
>
> `os.supports`_fd A `Set object indicating which functions in the os
>   module permit specifying their path parameter as an open file
>   descriptor`. Different platforms provide different functionality, and
>   an option that might work on one might be unsupported on another. For
>   consistency’s sakes, functions that support fd always allow specifying
>   the parameter, but will raise an exception if the functionality is not
>   actually available.
>
> To check whether a particular function permits specifying an open file
>   descriptor for its path parameter, use the in operator on supports_fd.
>   As an example, this expression determines whether os.chdir() accepts
>   open file descriptors when called on your local platform:

```
os.chdir in os.supports_fd
```

Minhas dúvidas são:

- O que é um `descritor de arquivo`?
- O que é um `descritor de diretório aberto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O módulo `os` dá acesso a certos recursos de baixo nível, **raramente utilizados na programação em python normal**. Um exemplo são essas funções que lidam diretamente com os descritores de arquivo e de diretório.

Em sistemas baseados em UNIX, quando tem um recurso de entrada e saída aberto, ele é associado a um número inteiro não negativo, que é chamado `descritor`... Um descritor de arquivo é portanto um indicador que é usado para fazer referência a este arquivo ao utilizar chamadas de sistema.

Descritores de arquivo fazem parte da API de programação POSIX, por isso, todo unix-like tem essa característica.

Descritores de diretório são a mesma coisa, porém, servem para manipular um diretório do sistema de arquivos. Existem também outros descritores como pipes ou de rede (sockets).

Por exemplo podemos usar `os.open()` para fazer uma chamada de baixo nível, passando como parâmetro a flag em hexadecimal 0x41 que indica que queremos criar um arquivo em modo de escrita:

```
>>> fd = os.open('/tmp/teste.txt', 0x41)
>>> print(fd)
3
```

O retorno da função é o "descritor de arquivo" para o arquivo aberto. Neste caso o número inteiro 3. Todas as operações de baixo nível que eu for fazer com o arquivo, preciso passar esse número 3:

```
>>> os.write(fd, b'hello')
5   # < - número de bytes escritos
```

Ou seja, serve pra isso, sempre que quiser referenciar a esse arquivo que está aberto, posso passar o número 3:

```
>>> os.write(3, b' world\n')
7
>>> os.close(3)
```

Verificando o conteúdo do arquivo:

```
>>> open('/tmp/teste.txt').read()
'hello world\n'
```

Termino a resposta voltando a lembrar que estes métodos de baixo nível não devem ser utilizados em programas normais; Eles são mais difíceis de operar corretamente, e podem ser causas de bugs em seus programas. Raramente é preciso usar um desses métodos.

Comment: Mais uma vez, muito obrigado pela resposta esclarecedora. Agradeço.